# Module Multi-instance in OrchardCMS

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, orchardcms

assuming i have a contacts orchard module which manages contacts

can i have two instance like so

mysite.com/WorkContacts/...

mySite.com/HomeContacts/....

and have the data partitioned by instance/location type etc.

I assume it should be but want to be sure before i dig any deeper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's **not** possible by default (although I'm not saying impossible at all). 
Each module has it's **unique, hardcoded Id** which prevents multi-instancing of modules by design. There are also many other reasons why it wouldn't be a good idea...

Achieving such behavior is possible of course, but in slightly different way. As Orchard is mainly about content, you are free to build your own, different content types for different contact types from existing parts and fields. And then you're free to create instances of those. It's described very well [here](http://www.orchardproject.net/docs/Creating-custom-content-types.ashx).

HTH

Comment: not sure of why it won't be a good idea if it's part of the design, after all event the communitystarterkit circa 2003 supported it out of the box for the reasons in op

Comment: I meant that it wouldn't be a good idea in this particular case. Orchard has a design to which multi-instancing modules just doesn't fit. Module is a thing that adds some *new* feature (eg. new content type), so there is no reason to add that twice. Creating and partitioning data happens on a *content definition* level, not on a module level. You can achieve that feature you told about without any problem, but what I'm saying is that multi-instancing modules is not a way is should be done in Orchard.

Comment: The best way to go would be to allow creating multiple contact lists in a single module. You could eg. create a ContactList type, which has a RoutePart, ContainerPart (and maybe others) and a Contact type, which has a RoutePart and ContainablePart (and others). User would then create a contact list (or two, three, fifty) from admin GUI and add appropriate contacts to each of them. Much more flexible than multi-instancing.

Answer (score 0):

This would probably be better asked over on the Orchard sites.

If you look at blogs functionality you can have multiple of those, following a similar pattern of code you could have multiple of the contacts modules.

The path /HomeContacts ... etc would be set through the routing functionality of Orchard.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for might the multi-tenancy module, available from the gallery. The only difference with what you describe is that the instances would need different server names rather than subfolders like you decribed.
Then again it's not quite clear whether you only want to separate just the data for that module (in which case the suggestion to model it after blog is a good one) or for the whole site (that would be multi-tenancy).

Comment: multi-tenancy is different from the example specified in the op